# How to re-enable double-tap to wake up option?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, settings, nokia-lumia-535, touch, personalization

I have been updated on W10M now. When I was on WP8.1, I disabled double-tap to wake up option. Now I want to re-enable that option but I couldn't find that option. I have searched all over including extras & info but now there's no such option. I am really wondering where had that option gone. What should I do now ? My phone's L535DS running Windows 10 Mobile if relevant.

settings => Personalization => Lock screen does not have any option:

[image]

And in Extras I can't even find **Touch** option.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Go to settings => Personalization => Lock screen (at the end of the page you will see double tap for wake up

[Sorry because picture is on my language](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFh7G.png)

Update: For L535 go to Settings => Extras => Touch, you will see first option for double tap for wake up

[L535](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LcLqN.jpg)

Comment: I don't have an option there :( . See the edit

Comment: I updated my answer

Comment: Lol There's not even Touch option. I have updated my question as well. I am really wondering where had that option gone.

Comment: Nokia account??? Is it real L535 ? Becuse it's MS's product not Nokia's

Comment: Yup it's real and the thing what matters is that I used double tap for wake up option for about 3 months when I was on WP8.1.

Comment: Are you on last build? My sister have L535 and she has double tap option.

Comment: Can you please upload the screenshot of her phone? I am on last build released on fas ring i.e. 14977. See my very first screenshot.

Comment: I updated with photo, because you are in Insider this update will arrive later for non insider user.

Comment: It says that My device is up to date.

Comment: Yeah because you are in insider program, so you have few update in front of us. (non insider users)

Comment: I don't know answer on that question go to feedback hub and ask MS